# How To Uncheck Respond To Client Computers Requesting Service In AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I uncheck the "Respond to client computers requesting service" in Active Directory using Powershell?

I tried looking in the `DirectoryEntry` properties and methods but couldn't see anything relevant.

[image: Active Directory checkbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. You need to use the intellimirrorSCP object class:

```
$directoryEntry = New-Object 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry'    
$directoryEntry.Path = $LdapPath
$searcher = New-Object 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher'($directoryEntry)    
$searcher.SearchScope = [System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope]::SubTree    
$searcher.PageSize = [System.Int32]::MaxValue
$searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=intellimirrorSCP)(name='ServerNameHere-Remote-Installation-Services'))"
$result = $searcher.FindOne()
$directoryEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
$directoryEntry.Properties.netbootAnswerRequests[0] = $false
$directoryEntry.CommitChanges()
```